# jQuery Selector

Tags: jquery

I want to achieve going to the parent element then to the prev element get the atrribute id of the element which has class: classname.

```
<div>

<span><span id="190" class="classname">blabla</span></span>

<span><a href="#" class="button">blabla</a></span>

</div>
```

Pseudo code:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
 console.log($(this).parent().prev().$(".classname").attr("id"));
});
```

Do I have to use a find here or is there another way?

Answer (score 4):

For your example:

```
$(this).parent().prev().children( '.classname' ).attr( 'id' );
```

Answer (score 1):

By the way, the id "190" is invalid, id and name attributes must begin with a letter, not a digit.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `find` as you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Find seems like the shortest way to get there....

```
alert($(this).parents("div").find(".classname").attr( 'id' ));
```

or

```
alert($(this).parents("div").find("span span").attr( 'id' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

as Ivanfosson has stated, you can use his advice only if you know the finite number of steps or layers down DOM the element you are searching, but if the `<div>` you placed is relative to some other divs and you can also use `find` and then do

```
$(this).parent().prev().children( '.classname' ).attr( 'id' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the context feature, like so:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    console.log( $('.classname', $(this).parent() ).attr('id') );
});
```